# Can't open large (3Gb) gri raster layer, generated through R, in ArcGIS

Tags: r, arcgis, raster

I am trying to use  ArcGIS to open a raster layer map, with .grd/gri extension, but ArcGIS keeps saying it's an invalid raster layer and does not open it. I am trying to convert it to .asc to see if ArcMap can open it, but I don't know how to do that.

Any other ideas on how I can open that file in ArcMap? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Arcgis does not opern grd files well. Use the raster package and save it in any other geo referenced format you want:

```
writeRaster(raster_name, output_filename, format="ascii", overwrite=TRUE)
```

Since you mention that your image is rather large, you may consider using the function argument 'datatype' to set the most efficient way of storing the data (e.g.,  datatype='INT1U' of your raster has only integer values between 0 and 255). This can dramatically reduce the size of the image if appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

In R you can also do:

```
library(raster)
r <- raster('filename.grd')
hdr(r, 'VRT')
```

and now open the VRT (header file) in ArcGIS